# jquery select test input inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="col-md-6">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Add. Subnet</label>
        <div id="divaddedsubnets" class="col-md-6">
            <input id="addedsubnets" name="addedsubnets" type="text" data-role="tagsinput" readonly="readonly" style="display: none;">
            <div class="bootstrap-tagsinput">
                here I should catch thi://<input type="text" placeholder="" style="width: 3em !important;">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

there a simple div element above I need to get that input field by jquery selector; I try like these;

`$("#divaddedsubnets > div input[type='text']"),$("#divaddedsubnets > div > input")`

none of works..

Comment: Can you reproduce this on `jsfiddle`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `>` for direct children

```
$("#divaddedsubnets > input")
```

```js
$("#divaddedsubnets > input").css('background', 'green');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Add. Subnet</label>
  <div id="divaddedsubnets" class="col-md-6">
    <input id="addedsubnets" name="addedsubnets" type="text" data-role="tagsinput" readonly="readonly">
    <div class="bootstrap-tagsinput">
      here I should catch thi://
      <input type="text" placeholder="" style="width: 3em !important;">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Use a `space` for direct/nested children

```
$("#divaddedsubnets input")
```

```js
$("#divaddedsubnets input").css('background', 'green');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Add. Subnet</label>
  <div id="divaddedsubnets" class="col-md-6">
    <input id="addedsubnets" name="addedsubnets" type="text" data-role="tagsinput" readonly="readonly">
    <div class="bootstrap-tagsinput">
      here I should catch thi://
      <input type="text" placeholder="" style="width: 3em !important;">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: *I try like these; `$("#divaddedsubnets > div input[type='text']")`, `$("#divaddedsubnets > div > input")` none of works.* Can you explain this